# Firebase 3 - How to structure database for individual/group messaging: many-to-many, perhaps?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to Firebase data modeling and I've been trying to figure out the most efficient and scalable way to create a data store for users who want to message other users, or even being part of a group where everyone in the group is sending messages to that single group.

Use case 1: A user messages another user for the first time (no conversation is created) and it is only limited to those two users.

Use case 2: More than 2 users send messages to the conversation. Users can be added or removed at anytime. Similar, to say, Facebook's messaging.

I believe this would be a many-to-many relationship, and after reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) on how to structure a database (and even trying to model my data based on their example), I've come up with the following:

```
{
      users: {
        mcbean: {
          conversations: {
             convo1: true,
             convo2: true,
          }
        },
        orion: {
          conversations: {
            convo1: true,
            convo2: true,
          }
        },
        leguy: {
          conversations: {
            convo2: true,
          }
        }
      },
      conversations: {
        convo1: {
          type: "individual"
          last_message: "this was the last thing said in the convo",
          created_at: 1463315112,
          users: {
            mcbean: true,
            orion: true
          }
        },
        convo2: {
          type: "group"
          last_message: "this was the also the last thing said in the convo",
          created_at: 1463315112,
          users: {
            mcbean: true,
            orion: true,
            leguy: true
          }
        }
      },
      conversation_messages: {
        convo1: {
          m1: {
            photo_url: "https://cdn.madeupthing.com/profile-img.png"
            body: "Let's get this party started",
            created_at: 1463315112
          },
          m2: { ... },
          m3: { ... }
        }
      }
    }
```

Is this what I am looking for? I'm building my app with Ionic 2 (and Angular 2 by extension), and I just want to make sure this would be the easiest to read/update. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks good as I understand it (also a noob). Below is documentation supporting this schema for others to click (which Im sure you saw).  Let us know if its working well.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout